# images Collection in Edit form symfony

Tags: image, forms, symfony, file-upload, collections

I am using multiple images uploading as a collection in symfony.

while Editing the image how to display image as collection as I am getting input type file blank..
And also I want delete link on previous collection n edit form..

Answer (score 0):

Symfony has a "built in" method to handle collections in forms, especially add/edit/delete.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

I say "built in" because it requires you to do some manual work (in Javascript).

Comment: default method of delete is only applicable on new added collections. not in already added collections in edit form

Comment: No. You can delete them if you compare the already persisted entity with the entity that came out of your form and remove/unset/whatever the ones that are not in the entity that came out of your form.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-tags-to-be-removed

Comment: i dont want to remove or delete bydefault i want delete link on every collection image on edit form.

Comment: Yes, that is what you can do. 
You add a delete link to every image and remove the whole form part of that image when clicked.
In the form submit function in the Controller you then get the Entity from your Database and compare it to the Entity you get through the handling of the Request parameter (inside the "$form->isValid()").